# About the date picker of the calendar

Tags: iphone

I have a small query, i m developing a calendar application for the iPhone,but i have stuck at a certain point, In xcode there is only a data-picker and this element is not functional in my app because in my app the user must be fast to choose date time. I would to use another instrument for chose a date.

Hey guys please help me.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but it sounds like you need a way for the user to pick a date/time?  Have you seen [`UIDatePicker`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html)?

Answer (score 0):

From your question I can't exactly see what the problem is... the SDK includes [UIDatePicker](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html), which you can [configure](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIDatePickerMode) to allow picking the date and time.